# How to set Authorized App Engine applications in Cloud SQL instance

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, cloud

Authorized App Engine Applications.

Only apps listed here will be allowed to access your Cloud SQL instance. These must be located in the same region.

what I should input in application ID?
how to get Application ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are after the application identifier - which if your app engine app is at http://abc.appspot.com is "abc"

If you're not using app engine then you might need to set up other access rules, like IP address ranges